# Chrome Browser Headless problem : Some specific pages are not rendering in Headless mode

Tags: java, python-3.x, selenium, google-chrome, automation

I am trying to automate a process using selenium and chrome browser in Python.
My browser works correctly for most pages but is unable to render a few pages including `chrome://version/`. 
For general automation(without headless) it returns the page and page source correctly, whereas for **headless** browsing it returns a blank page with page source as below

```
<html><head></head><body></body></html>
```

I have tried chrome in the different operating system including OpenSUSE, fedora, and Windows. 
I have tried many things like:
Removing all the initial arguments,
Used the browser with headless off.
For Reference:
 If I run this code

```
from selenium.webdriver import Chrome
from selenium.webdriver import ChromeOptions
options = ChromeOptions()
# to remove all arguments
options.add_experimental_option( 'excludeSwitches', ['disable-hang-monitor', 'disable-prompt-on-repost', 'disable-background-networking', 'disable-sync', 'disable-translate', 'disable-web-resources', 'disable-client-side-phishing-detection', 'disable-component-update', 'disable-default-apps', 'disable-zero-browsers-open-for-tests', '--enable-automation', '--use-mock-keychain', '--user-data-dir', '--enable-blink-features', '--disable-popup-blocking', '--enable-logging --force-fieldtrials=SiteIsolationExtensions/Control', '--enable-logging', '--force-fieldtrials', '--ignore-certificate-errors', '--load-extension', '--log-level', '--no-first-run','--password-store','--remote-debugging-port','--test-type'
]) 
options.add_argument("--headless")
options.add_argument("--no-sandbox")
browser = Chrome(executable_path=driver_path,options=options)
browser.get("chrome://version")
print(browser.page_source)
```

It returns the same blank page for **headless**

```
<html><head></head><body></body></html>
```

If the chrome is operated without headless option it will work completely fine.

```
<!doctype html>
<!--
about:version template page
-->
<html id="t" dir="ltr" lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>About Version</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="chrome://resources/css/text_defaults.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="chrome://version/about_version.css">
......................
```

Comment: from looking at the chromedriver verbose logging, I can see net::ERR_INVALID_URL. looks like when running headless, driver won't accept loading URLS which are not in format of "http". what are you trying to get from chrome://version page? maybe we can try to workaround it?

Comment: @AdiOhana I am facing the same problem in case of some html pages. chrome://version is just an example.

Comment: Having the same issue. Scraping works perfectly without the headless tag, with it it just doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

You might try using the argument:

```py
options.add_argument("--headless=chrome")
```